# dynamic looping on a controller property

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I am using ember `2.17`.

I added this property to a `controller`:

```js
export default Controller.extend({
  newAttachments: new Array()
  ...
})
```

I add elements in it through this controller `action`:

```js
setAttachment(file) {
  console.log('trying');
  this.get('newAttachments').push(file);
}
```

When I use the action, the message is displayed in the console, and in Ember inspector I can see the array is no longer empty :

[image]

However, the following code in the view has no output :

```
{{#each newAttachments as |file|}}
  <p>in loop</p>
{{/each}}
```

Why is it not displaying anything? In a component it would work, why not here ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ember can't observe native arrays. Therefor the framework doesn't know that a value is pushed into the array. You should use ember's own [`Ember.NativeArray`](https://api.emberjs.com/ember/3.9/classes/Ember.NativeArray) and it's [`pushObject` method](https://api.emberjs.com/ember/3.9/classes/Ember.NativeArray/methods/pushObject?anchor=pushObject) instead. That one ensures that the framework is informed if an entry is added to or removed from array. Changed code would look like this:

```js
import { A } from '@ember/array';

export default Controller.extend({
  newAttachments: A(),

  setAttachment(file){
    this.get('newAttachments').pushObject(file)
  }
})
```

You shouldn't add the array as a property of an `EmberObject` as this might introduce a leak between instances. That's not a production issue in that case cause controllers are singletons in ember.js. But you might see strange behavior in tests. Refactoring for [native classes](https://www.pzuraq.com/coming-soon-in-ember-octane-part-1-native-classes/) will resolve that issues as class fields are not leaked between instances. For old EmberObject based classes initializing the value in `init` hook or using a computed property are common ways to deal with that issue:

```js
// computed property
import { computed } from '@ember/object';
import { A } from '@ember/array';

export default Controller.extend({
  newAttachments: computed(() => A()),
});
```

```js
// init hook
import { A } from '@ember/array';

export default Controller.extend({
  init() {
    this._super(...arguments);

    this.set('newAttachments', A());
  }
});
```

Please note that you don't need to use `get()` if running Ember >= 3.1.